# Firebase database collection rendering List

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase database in my project. When I retrieve my data the payload looks like this:

```
{
   -randomId123: {name: "foo", surname: "bar" },
   ....
}
```

How can I correctly render my list in my component:

```
export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(dummyData);

  const items = data.map((v) => {
      console.log(v.val())
  });

 setData(items)

  return (
    <div>
      <> {data.map((d) => {
              <p> {d.key} {d.name} {d.surname} </p>
  })} </>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Expected output:

```
<p> randomId123 foo bar <p>
```

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {-randomId123 , -randomId456, -randomId789}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an `object`.

```
{
   -randomId123: {name: "foo", surname: "bar" },
   ....
}
```

If this were `data`, then one may not be able to iterate using `data.map()`.

In order to render:

```
<p> randomId123 foo bar <p>
```

Please try below:

```
<div>
  {Object.keys(data).map(k => (
    <p> {k} {data[k].name} {data[k].surname} </p>
  )}
</div>
```